# Flannel installation on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I have installed fresh Kubernetes 1.6.2 master on a single host and now trying to start Flannel using https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

The pod does not come up:

```
$ kubectl get pods kube-flannel-ds-l6gn4 --namespace kube-system   
NAME                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-flannel-ds-l6gn4   1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   36         2h

$ kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-l6gn4 --namespace kube-system kube-flannel
E0427 15:35:52.232093       1 main.go:127] Failed to create 
SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-l6gn4': the server does not allow access to the requested resource (get pods kube-flannel-ds-l6gn4)
```

I've also tried this using the default serviceaccount, but it won't come up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the RBAC authorizer, you also need to create https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml to set up the role and permissions for the flannel service account

Answer (score 10):

Note that to install Kubernetes with flannel you need to specify the `--pod-network-cidr` flag. See [kubeadm init section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubeadm#kubeadm-init)

Example

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

then as Menionned by Jordan, on some environments you need to install [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

If you are still having issues check that

1. Make sure your cni plugin binaries are in place in /opt/cni/bin. You should see corresponding binaries for each CNI add-on
2. Make sure the CNI configuration file for the network add-on is in place under /etc/cni/net.d
   [root@node1]# ls /etc/cni/net.d
   10-flannel.conf
3. Run ifconfig to check docker, flannel bridge and virtual interfaces are up

as mentionned here on github
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36575#issuecomment-264622923

I have written a [complete blog post on the topic](https://ronanquillevere.github.io/2017/05/16/kubernetes-ovh.html#.WSwwdxJ96V4) if it can help.

Comment: gist link broken

Comment: They moved RBAC to Legacy, therefore, you might want use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml .

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who may be looking for this more recently, the [most recent docs](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) state that the correct provisioning command (For RBAC-enabled 1.7+) is:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Note that there are also [instruction docs for older versions](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kubernetes.md)/without RBAC, which state:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-legacy.yml
```

Note that to install RBAC on top of the older version:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

Comment: RBAC links are expired, what's the new one?